# It is ridiculous that people like me can nominate

Tags: feature-request, election

You should have at least 10.000 reputation, and be active for at least a year, otherwise the nominations get spoiled with kiddos like me that have no chance, and should not have a chance to become a moderator.

I mean  look at this, users that are active for only 1.5 month, or 6 months are nominating... People with less than 500 reputation... Those people probably have yet to discover that there also exists a meta associated to MSE.

If you vote for me, which I don't recommend at all, I will do my utmost best to make sure next moderator elections only people that are active for at least a year and have at least 10000 reputation can nominate.

---

Edit: I agree Shog9, this is a better place for this. Personally I think any candidate with less than 3000 points, is less than a year active or has no meta activity should not be in the list. So if the system is not going to change this year, I would like to ask nominees to withdraw voluntarily if they don't meet any of those standards.

Comment: As this did not appear to be a serious nomination, I've withdrawn it from the election. As it *did* appear to be a serious plea for assistance, I've moved it here to Meta and posted a response. I hope this is acceptable to you - please let me know if I can do anything else to assist here.

Comment: @Shog: Did you add the [featured] tag? It doesn't appear on the revision history!

Comment: Consider the phrase "moved it here to meta" to contain implications of a fair bit of slight of hand, @Asaf.

Comment: @AsafKaragila My translation: Shog9 copied the text of "nomination", created the post (with tags and all), and used his database access rights to assign the post ownership to Kasper. A "regular" Community Manager, like Grace Note, would not be able to do it.

Comment: Actually, GN would be able to do something like this, @Behaviour - this is one of the more obscure support tools we usually reserve for instances where the account system screws up somehow, but can be repurposed for edge-cases. Note that it probably also broke the functionality of the [featured] tag, so... Too clever by half.

Comment: @Shog9 Grace Note told me [can't migrate it, no](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18982336#18982336)... so perhaps the tool is a little **too** obscure.

Comment: @Shog9 How about [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/election/5#post-1059547) as well?

Comment: Related discussion: [How much experience should a potential moderator have?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/17671/)

Comment: Why is this [featured] ??

Comment: Kasper, you should seriously nominate yourself, giving more than just these reasons.

Comment: @Behaviour I said I couldn't migrate it. This wasn't migration though, and is something I could pull off.

Comment: with over 250 members having 10K+ rep, I agree. For less active, lower rep boards, a lower number right apply.

Answer (score 46):

You're right - this election *is* looking a bit ridiculous right now. Not that I don't believe most of the candidates are sincere in their desire to help... But this site has over 4 years of history, nuanced policies have grown up, and expecting someone who hasn't spent a lot of time here to even *know* about them - much less uphold them - is kinda silly.

The current requirements for nomination made sense 4 years ago when Mathematics held its *first* election (IIRC, the first election in this format anywhere on Stack Exchange!) - but y'all have grown since then, and it's time the election requirements changed to reflect that.

Changing the rules after folks have already nominated in good faith is a bit sketchy. Such changes should be discussed at length and made known well before an election starts - so the most drastic alterations will have to wait for next year.

But there's one thing we can and should do: **reduce the number of nomination slots available**. Conscientious voters (or potential nominees) shouldn't have to wade through dozens of posts from folks who, realistically, aren't going to figure in the final election. So effective immediately, I've lowered it from 30 to 20.

### What this change means

Immediately, nothing changes. No current nominations are being forcibly withdrawn. However...

- The reputation threshold for nomination immediately becomes the lowest reputation of the current set of nominees.
- For every *new* nomination, the candidate with the lowest reputation score is automatically withdrawn, and the new threshold for nomination becomes the reputation of the new lowest-reputation candidate.
- Effectively, this puts the election into a mode whereby **you** - the eligible members of Mathematics - decide what the minimum allowable reputation should be for nominees. Want it higher? **Convince higher-reputation users to post *serious* nominations.**

I sincerely believe this will help reduce the strain on both candidates and voters, but we'll also be keeping a closer eye on how this election progresses to make sure future nominees are serious in their intentions - I know how much the selection of competent moderators matters to y'all, and pledge to do all I can to prevent this democratic process from being abused.

Finally, I want to apologize for not anticipating the need for more strict requirements sooner. Last time around, there was [concern](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9286/how-to-ensure-candidates-pre-commit-for-next-election) that there wouldn't even be enough candidates for a Primary phase - this time, y'all hit that threshold within a day. Which solved one problem, but brought others with it.

Comment: Does the reduction to 20 nominees apply only to this site, or more widely?

Comment: Currently just this site; we may expand it if it works out well here. There are no other elections currently underway.

Comment: So you can't nominate yourself for a moderator now? :\

Comment: Go for it, @Asaf

Comment: How should I go for it? I can't nominate anyone other than myself, certainly not you! :-)

Comment: You could always preface your nomination with "Shog said I should stop waffling and nominate myself, so..." @Asaf ;-)

Comment: I will, as a joke, and then you'll have to remove it and scold me. Can we just skip to the end instead? :-)

Comment: Please nominate and push out a newbie, @Asaf Karagila!

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Watch out. Shog's clearly demonstrated a mastery of the tools. You might find yourself volunteered.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.

Comment: @Arthur: Then the game would be determined, and I will have no choice. Can you see why I'm sorta okay with that? :P

Comment: @Arthur: Not to mention that I'd be forced to do it, which is also nice. And we can say that in the Church of SE, Shog9 is a large cardinal too. (Okay, that's just one set theory joke too many. I'll be quiet now.)

Comment: I disagree with this point: "But this site has over 4 years of history, nuanced policies have grown up, and expecting someone who hasn't spent a lot of time here to even know about them - much less uphold them - is kinda silly." This produces [group think](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupthink) since the moderators would be homogeneous which isn't a benefit to the community.

Comment: @dustin - In general, policies have been decided on by the community, not imposed by moderators (although they help enforce them).  So anyone who disagrees with those policies shouldn't be a moderator, simply because they will be making decisions which the majority of users disagree with.  That said, if they're explicit about disagreeing in their nomination, and still get enough votes to become a moderator, that's good incentive to review those policies.

Comment: @Bobson that is tru with many communities (governments as well) both real and online but group think has never shown to be effective and leads to more issues then good. One, it can make new members feel alienate or discriminated against if they aren't of that mind set, and as long as they aren't in the wrong, that shouldn't occur.

Comment: @Bobson: It’s entirely possible to be a moderator and make decisions on the basis of rules and customs that are contrary to one’s own views; I’ve been in a very similar situation elsewhere. One allows one’s own views to color one’s decision only in edge cases, and then only within limits. It is, however, important for a moderator to know what the group’s policies and customs are, and voters certainly have a right to know a candidate’s views on issues that are known to be contentious, and whether the candidate understands the need to subordinate those views to policy and accepted custom.

Comment: @Brian: Yes, it is entirely possible. It is also entirely possible that one claims that they would, but then acts in the entirely opposite way! In fact, knowing the nuanced history of this community is enough to remember that both thing do in fact happen.

Comment: @Asaf: All true, unfortunately.

Comment: @dustin: As you're appearing on the candidate list you should be aware full well to what has been said here. Moderators rarely set policies, they enforce them. If you plan on setting policies yourself you will be a bad moderator, and you will be impeached. Even if in your own eyes the actions you took are for the good of the site.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott - You're entirely right.  That's what I was thinking at the time ("disagrees" -> "actively disagrees and won't follow"), I just failed to actually get that thought out of my head.  You have to know what the policies are to be *able* to disagree, too.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I never said anything about setting policies. Changing homogeneous groups is what prevents what I said. This is in regards to this line: "But this site has over 4 years of history, nuanced policies have grown up, and expecting someone who hasn't spent a lot of time here to even know about them - much less uphold them - is kinda silly." This comment is promoting a homogeneous group of leaders which only benefits one class of user the ones like them.

Comment: Shuuuucks, @dustin - I've been around forever and i still don't understand everything these folks do. Dont take this personally.

Comment: @dustin: It is true, though. Unless, of course, you feel that there should be a big change. Of course, you don't have to be a moderator for leading such change. And again, we had a "diverse" moderators group before and nothing was done, and it ended up a catastrophe.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I think you should nominate yourself, if you've the time for the job that is.

Comment: *Everyone* thinks Asaf should nominate himself --- except Asaf. Unfortunately, Asaf's vote on this outweighs those of the rest of m.se combined.

Comment: @Gerry: Some might say "fortunately". :-)

Comment: @Asaf "Arthur: Then the game would be determined, and I will have **no choice**." <- Does this mean that if we all agree to only do math without (Axiom of) Choice, you will run?

Comment: @Jyrki: No, but if I will have no choice, then I might be okay with this.

Comment: @Gerry, any chance of you running? I guess I will, but you might be more ... moderate :-)

Comment: @Jyrki, being moderate is, I think, precisely the attribute I lack when it comes to this position. But let me encourage you to put your name up.

Comment: Currently, the list of nominees includes 22 candidates. Could you please remove by hand the two with lowest score to avoid confusion?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo They are left in there by design: if someone withdraws, they again become eligible. The message at the very bottom of the page explains: there are 22 candidates but only 20 are eligible to participate in the primaries.

Comment: @Gerry: When we met that one time you seemed very moderate. I suspect you might be lying! :-)

Comment: @Asaf, I was on my best behavior then. Evidence of my immoderation is readily available, both on meta and on main.